# grml's zsh config - multiline command re-echoing

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I installed grml's configuration files and something in those files seems to be causing
multiline commands to re-echo themselves before executing. For example

```
user@machine ~ % cat << EOF
\`heredoc> this 
\`heredoc> that
\`heredoc> EOF

this
that
EOFthis
that
user@machine ~ %
```

I looked at the options that were set but none of them seem to be responsible.

Do you guys know how to disable that echoing so that the above is just

```
...
\`heredoc> EOF

this
that
user@machine ~ %
```

(with or without that blank line)

Answer (score 0):

Using the configuration grabbed with:

```
# IMPORTANT: please note that you might override an existing
# configuration file in the current working directory! =>
wget -O .zshrc http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/zsh/zshrc
# Optionally also grab the user configration:
# wget -O .zshrc.local  http://git.grml.org/f/grml-etc-core/etc/skel/.zshrc
```

(from [here](http://grml.org/zsh/)), I can't replicate this issue. I have attempted to replicate both with and without the user configuration (`~/.zshrc.local` in the above configuration):

```
simont@charizard ~ % cat << EOF
\`heredoc> this
\`heredoc> that
\`heredoc> EOF
this
that
simont@charizard ~ %
```

Without further information it's difficult to provide a conclusive answer to this question. To fully answer, some things are needed:

- the contents of your `~/.zshrc`,
- the contents of [other files zsh loads](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshall) [see the "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" section].

I'd recommend loading a fresh shell with `zsh -f`, then slowly adding in sections of your config until you replicate this behaviour.